# Toggling several checkboxes on separate toggle change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have several checkboxes, or, should I say, several [bootstrap toggles](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/):

```
<input id="master-toggle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" class="slave-toggle" data-toggle="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" class="slave-toggle" data-toggle="toggle">
```

What I'm trying to do is toggle every `slave-toggle` when the `master-toggle` is toggled. To do that, I wrote the following code:

```
$('#master-toggle').change(() =>  {
   if($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('.slave-toggle').each(() => {
          $(this).prop('checked', true).change();
      });
   } else {
      $('.slave-toggle').each(() => {
          $(this).prop('checked', false).change();
      });
   }
});
```

So, when the `master-toggle` is toggled, the function executes, checking the value of the "checked" property. If the "checkbox" is "checked", then it iterates over all elements of the `slave-toggle` class, and sets their "checked" property to true. Same thing for when `master-toggle` is "unchecked". Right?

Well the thing is, I've run into 2 issues. First, the `$(this).prop('checked')` expression in the `if` statement always evaluates to `undefined`. Second, even if I force this value, executing the `$(this).prop('checked', true).change()` inside the `each` function doesn't change either `slave-toggle`'s status. What gives? What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/50278/) link.

Comment: $(this).is(':checked')

Comment: ...always returns false in my example. And this [one](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/#events) uses `.prop()`, so why shouldn't I?

Comment: You are using arrow functions.  Arrow functions do not change what `this` is.  You should use normal functions for the eaches

Comment: @Taplar, that did it ;) thank you so much. Why does that happen tho, do you have any reference where I could read about it?

Comment: You can search for "Javascript ES6 arrow functions" and it should turn up some articles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues you are running into are in regards to your use of arrow functions.

```
() => {}
```

Arrow functions **do not** change what `this` is within their context.  It is one of their features.  In order to reference `this` as you are expecting, use normal functions.  Otherwise, the `e.target` on the change event should be the element changed, and the `each` method should pass in the arguments `index, element` that you can reference.